# How can I find out the Google Voice calling history in the Gmail plugin?

Tags: gmail, google-voice

In Gmail, there used to be a plugin at lower left corner for using Gtalk to call other people. When I click the phone icon, there was a list of recent phone numbers that I have called.

Now Gtalk has retired, the lower left corner still shows the phone icon, but when I click it, there is no list of recent phone numbers, but a list of phone numbers ordered by their owners' names.

How shall I get a list of recent call numbers in the Gmail webpage, and redial one recent number quickly? (I know that I can find out my history in Google Voice webpage, but I want to do it from Gmail).

Comment: May be in hangouts [View call history through Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3205299?hl=en).

Answer (score 8):

From: [View call history through Hangouts on your computer - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3205299?hl=en)

> You can view your call history for phone calls made through Hangouts
> or Google Voice calls in Hangouts. If you have a Google Voice number,
> your call history will also show calls made to and from your Google
> Voice number.
>
> Here's how to view your call history for Hangouts on your computer:
>
> ## In Gmail
>
> 1. Open Hangouts in [Gmail](http://gmail.com/) .
> 2. Click the phone tab  [image: phone icon].
> 3. Next to the search box, click the add credit icon [image: Add credit icon].
> 4. [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice#history) will open, where you can view your complete call history.

Comment: This is stupendously hard to figure out on your own.  Note that [these instructions](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/187933?hl=en) appear not to work, at least if you have Google Voice.

Comment: @JessRiedel The referred instruction aren't available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I only just now figured this out. I've been going to [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com).

This also lets you add the number to your contacts.